# JavaFX: Remove empty rows from tableview

Tags: javafx, tableview, tablerow

By default `tableview` have at least 15 rows. So if I have 10 elements in my table then 5 rows will be empty.
*How can I remove such rows(not fill up it by white color through CSS)?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [TableView: adjust number of visible rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298337/tableview-adjust-number-of-visible-rows)

Comment: See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298337/tableview-adjust-number-of-visible-rows

Answer (score 3):

You can do this. There is no *public* API present to call the `visibleRowCount` in `TableView`.

But, @kleopatra has created a very nice implementation of TableView called as `TableViewWithVisibleRowCount`, which has a `visibleRowCount` and you can play with it. [You can check it out here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26364210/1759128).

Since you don't need css implenetation, I am not including them here.

*N.B. - They could be found [here](http://fxexperience.com/2011/11/alternate-row-highlighting-in-empty-tableview-and-listview-rows/)*.