# How to make TableView to not show absent rows?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

By default, TableView shows colors for absent rows too:

[image]

Example is taken [from here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm) and a table has only 5 rows. Nevertheless, visually it still displays interleaving color for 6ht, 7th and so on rows.

How to avoid this? I wan't it be visible, that rows are ended.

Comment: Do you just want to remove the styling or do you intend to adjust the height as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TableView: adjust number of visible rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298337/tableview-adjust-number-of-visible-rows)

Comment: I want to remove these rows so that no any styling can re-appear them. They should be absent completely.

Comment: "Duplicate" question has no accepted answer as you see, i.e. it is providing workarounds but not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `empty` pseudo class (see [`Cell` CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#cell)) to set the background color of those rows from css:

E.g.

```css
.table-row-cell:empty {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

In case you use CSS to style odd/even cells yourself, you can simply add the `:filled` pseudoclass to all those selectors to only make them applicable to non-empty cells (assuming those selectors are for `Cell`s only). E.g.:

```css
.table-row-cell:empty {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.table-row-cell:odd:filled {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

.table-row-cell:even:filled {
    -fx-background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Or simply use more concrete selectors by using the selectors applying to table rows plus the `:empty` selector:

```css
.table-row-cell:empty:odd, .table-row-cell:empty:even {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.table-row-cell:odd {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

.table-row-cell:even {
    -fx-background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: How can I sure it won't interfere with odd-even styling?

Comment: @Dims: What do you mean by "interfere" with odd-even styling? Do you want the color to differ(ob be the same as) the one of the last row or something. Are you uncertain whether if the selector has a higher priority than `:odd` and `:even` selectors? Or something else???

Comment: @Dims: added 2 alternatives for that to my answer. I'd recommend using `:filled`, if possible.

Comment: You can also consider setting the "looked-up colors" used by modena. This removes ambiguity too: `.table-row-cell { -fx-control-inner-background: lightblue ; -fx-control-inner-background-alt: red ; }` and `.table-row-cell:empty { -fx-background-color: transparent ;}`

Comment: I want to provide a control with which end-user will be unable to style empty rows at all. They should really absent, not just colored out.

Comment: @Dims: Adding those empty rows is a "core" behavior of the default skin of `TableView`. Removing those rows probably requires you to modify (if not reimplement) the `Skin`... Good luck with that. Personally I haven't messed around with skins yet...