# Getting more number of rows than needed in javafx. how to solve this?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a table with some data but, Getting empty rows than needed.

The information I need is displayed and extra rows are showing how to remove those?

tried to keep it to height of the pane but not solved.

Table sample.java

```
public class TableSample extends Application {
TableView<Product> table;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        TableColumn<Product,String> nameColoumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameColoumn.setMinWidth(200);
        nameColoumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

        TableColumn<Product,Double> priceColoumn = new TableColumn<>("Price");
        priceColoumn.setMinWidth(200);
        priceColoumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));

        TableColumn<Product,Integer> quatityColoumn = new TableColumn<>("Quantity");
        quatityColoumn.setMinWidth(200);
        quatityColoumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quatity"));


        table=new TableView<>();
        table.setItems(getProduct());
        table.getColumns().addAll(nameColoumn,priceColoumn,quatityColoumn);


        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().add(table);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public ObservableList<Product> getProduct(){
        ObservableList<Product> products =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        products.add(new Product("laptopt",55,22));
        products.add(new Product("sjkad",56,52));
        products.add(new Product("qqqqq",42,52));
        products.add(new Product("ddd",25,42));
        products.add(new Product("www",72,5225));

        return products;
    }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a screenshot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TableView: adjust number of visible rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298337/tableview-adjust-number-of-visible-rows)