# How to set the number of rows visible at a time in a TableView (javafx)

Tags: javafx, tableview, row

I want to set the numbers of rows that I can see in a tableview at the same time (then scrolling the bar I can see the others). Anyone know how to do it?

For now I am able to do only this (in the example I want to show only 4 rows and I manually calculate the size of the rows). I know it is not a very clever solution, but so you have an idea of what I want to do:

```
table.setItems(books);
TableHeaderRow header = (TableHeaderRow) table.lookup("TableHeaderRow");
table.setFixedCellSize((table.getHeight()-header.getHeight())/4);
```

Comment: Please include what you have already tried, or what code you have so far. Your question doesn't really indicate your own effort which isn't really in line with Stack Overflow. Please consult this page to learn how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: not supported (and not really possible without setting the fixedCellSize) - you need a custom skin that overrides computePrefHeight

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TableView: adjust number of visible rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298337/tableview-adjust-number-of-visible-rows)

Comment: I think not, because here I have a fixed height for the table view and I want to show only a fixed number of rows (and if I understood well in the code you linked they want to resize the table view). I am updating the question with the best that I am able to do right now (I know it's a stupid solution, but for now I can not do anything better)

Comment: My guess is that you are going to have to set the `TableView` to a specific height and not allow it to be changed.

Comment: the duplicate explains _exactly_ what to do - the question doesn't matter, simply apply the solution to your context

Comment: @Sedrick if I understand the question correctly (might not be the case, though ;) your guess is incorrect

Comment: @kleopatra, there is a very good chance I don't understand the question.